# Bootstrap 4 how to create a responsive dashboard layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an idea for a dashboard which I like to create using Bootstrap. Please find the following image of the layout I would like to achieve using Bootstrap 4.

[Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmPez.png)

I can make everything happen but except the left box highlighted in red. Following is my current code and appreciate if anyone could help.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pbuxwqn9/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <!-- Side Nav Start -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav sidebar">
        <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
        <li class="nav-item active d-flex justify-content-center mt-12" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Dashboard">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    Side Menu
                </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="content-wrapper d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="content">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-top navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top border-bottom">
                <!-- Topbar Search -->
                <div class="logo mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100">Header</div>


            </nav>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
                    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Dashboard</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-5">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-5">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-5">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-nav {
    &.sidebar {
        width: 5.6rem !important;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #000;

        .nav-item {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
            margin: 15px 0;

            &.active {
                .nav-link {
                    color: #fff;
                    position: relative;


                }
            }

            &:hover {
                .nav-link {
                    color: #fff;
                }
            }

            .nav-link {
                color: #5C6A7C;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you exactly looking for, please state that in your question.

Comment: I can't get done the section highlighted in red in the attached image.

Comment: I mean, do you want it below `header` or increase the section's width or both, can you be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bg-info">

    <div class="container" style="padding: 20px">
        <p>Put your Navbar here </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-2 bg-warning" style="height: 100vh">
        <h4>Side Nav</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-10">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- for the padding in the main body -->
            <!-- an other row and cols for the inner content -->
            <h5 class="text-center">Main content</h5>
            <br /><br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-md-4">
                    <div class="container bg-danger" style="height: 50vh">
                        <h4>First Block</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-md-4">
                    <div class="container bg-success" style="height: 50vh">
                        <h4>First Block</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-md-4">
                    <div class="container bg-primary" style="height: 50vh">
                        <h4>First Block</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

The above code snipet would help.
using .row and .col classes will achieve the purpose.